# Sql statement returns null when there is actually a value

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I am using Flight framework at backend for building a RESTful service and PDO for retrieving data from MySql.

```
require 'flight/Flight.php';    

Flight::route('GET /satellites', function () {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM satellites";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $response = json_encode($stmt->fetchAll());
        $db = null;
        echo "{sucess: true, records:" . "$response" . "}";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":' . $e->getMessage() . '}}';
    }        
});

Flight::start();
```

I get this JSON in response:

```
{
    sucess: true, 
    records:[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "dates":"01.01.2007 - 01.01.2011",
            "satellite":null,
            null:"98.2",
            "resolution":"15",
            "band":"30",    
            "price":"$15"
        }
    ]
}
```

The above is correct, but satellite shouldn't be null, it definitely has a value (I checked it through PHPMyAdmin). Also there is a column called null with value 98.2, which should be called nadir. Why is it called null?

BTW, data type of satellite and nadir columns is varchar(255). I then changed satellite column datatype to text, but all the same.

Comment: What is your collation?

Comment: Have you checked whether it's a problem with `json_encode()`? What does `$stmt->fetchAll()` return?

Comment: why is the field name of db given as null

Comment: BTW, the text in database is copypasted from an odt document. If it matters.

Comment: how `null` can be field name (property)???

Comment: @ragol, yes, you're right. $stmt->fetchAll() returns a correct array. It seems the problem is in json_encode(). But how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Will you post the output of `var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());`?

Comment: @VINAYKr.SHARMA, `array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["dates"]=> string(23) "01.01.2007 - 01.01.2011" ["satellite"]=> string(9) "SAT­7" ["nadir­"]=> string(4) "98.2" ["resolution"]=> string(2) "15" ["band"]=> string(2) "30" ["price"]=> string(3) "$15" } }`

Comment: Why does the value of `satellite` has a string length of 9 when the value is "SAT7"?

Comment: I see now that in "SAT7" there is a strange non unicode character between "T" and "7". And this character is also in "nadir" after "r". `json_encode()` cannot convert them so it produces `null`. You probably copy pasted some invisible characters from the mentioned ODT document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your record there is something may be hidden characters, as your var_dump data shown:

```
array(1) {
 [0]=> array(10) {
  ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
  ["dates"]=> string(23) "01.01.2007 - 01.01.2011"
  ["satellite"]=> string(9) "SAT­7" // This 4 character is showing count 9
  ["nadir­"]=> string(4) "98.2"
  ["resolution"]=> string(2) "15"
  ["band"]=> string(2) "30"
  ["price"]=> string(3) "$15"
 }
}
```

Above `"SAT7"` is actually looking like 4 character word but it has some hidden characters, var_dump showing count. Similarly `"nadir"` has also hidden characters.

Fix above issue and continue

Here json output is giving this:

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "dates":"01.01.2007 - 01.01.2011",
    "satellite":"SAT\u00ad7", // Hidden characters in value
    "nadir\u00ad":"98.2", // Hidden characters in field
    "resolution":"15",
    "band":"30",
    "price":"$15"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  in  getConnection(); you use 
   // You might missing this line set utf8
   $pdoParams = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8;');

   $params = array(
    'host' => 'localhost',        'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'dbname' => 'dbname',
    'driver_options' => $pdoParams
   );
```